# Accessing output of RDKIT Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol,n)

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit, cheminformatics

I am attempting to use RDKIT Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol,n) function but am unable to callout the information from using this function. It runs, but I am unable to obtain the substructures.

Does anyone have suggestions on successfully calling out the information from the output of this function after it runs?

I am expecting an output, either in tuple or string form, that lists all substructures with Length N atoms. In my explicit case, I am looking for 4 atoms. Attached is code I have run with also listing the output errors.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
AllChem.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem import rdmolops

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C')
mol
```

```
structures = Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol,4)
structures
print(structures[1])
```

Output:
<rdkit.rdBase._vectint object at 0x0000024C16BBA2E0>

```
structures[0]
```

Output:
<rdkit.rdBase._vectint at 0x24c16ba62e0>

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert to `list()`.

And since `FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN` returns bonds and not atoms, you have to look for three bonds.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor
rdDepictor.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
IPythonConsole.drawOptions.addBondIndices = True

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C')
mol
```

[image]

```
threebonds = Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol, 3)

for n in threebonds:
    print(list(n))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 5]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 5, 4]
[2, 5, 3]
[2, 4, 3]
[3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this as well as previous questions

Answer (score 0):

A team member of mine was able to generate a code as to access the paths or subgraphs information. To clarify, paths don't have branching where subgraphs do.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
AllChem.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem import rdmolops
import csv

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C')
mol


# Find all subgraphs of length 3 in the molecule
#Subgraphs have branching
subgraphs = Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol, 3)

#Paths is no branching
#subgraphs = Chem.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(mol, 3)
print(len(subgraphs))

# Print out the connected SMILES for each subgraph
for subgraph in subgraphs:
    # Get the subgraph as a new molecule object
    sub_mol = Chem.PathToSubmol(mol, subgraph)
    # Generate the connected SMILES string for the subgraph
    subgraph_smiles = Chem.MolToSmiles(sub_mol, kekuleSmiles=True)
    print(subgraph_smiles)

Output
11
C=CCC
C=CCO
C=CCN
C=C(C)S
CCCS
OCCS
NCCS
CC(C)O
CC(C)N
CC(N)O
CC(N)O
```